# How to pack several files into one in order to go through them in a handmade file manager?

Tags: python-3.x

An application works with entities that consist of images and texts. For the program, several JPGs, PNGs, TIFFs, texts or jsons are considered as a one whole **work**, but they are a bunch of different files on a disk. It's convinient for a user to be able to easily copy **work**s, sent them to another people, download, upload etc. While a **work** is actually several files it's cumbersome to work with them for a user.

Probably, I can zip required files but it looks like a heavy workaround. I don't need compression, and speed of the application is important.

I'm not sure, may be, it's okay to just strictly read the whole data from each file and sequentially write it to a final file, construct it as a json or something else... but I suppose that a turnkey solution may be here.

My question:

How can I pack different files into one in order to go quickly through them, copy, move, delete, edit in a GUI application like any file manager does, and to be able for a person to manually copy **work**s, send to a friend etc.?

I code in Python.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try `tar`?

Comment: @DYZ, I didn't know what is it. As I've looked some articles about tar format, and it looks as what I need. Most likely, it's the simplest and the fastest way. Thank you!